# Search txt file and display data between all occurrences

Tags: python, regex

Extremely new to Python. I started off writing a PHP script to find all occurrences of 2 strings in a txt file but it's using too much memory so i read Python would be better.

Basically what i need to do is:
- import a txt file
- go through it and return all the data between the tags below
- remove any duplicates
- output the results

The bits i'm looking for look like this:

```
------DATA--------------------------------------------------
DATA TO SHOW
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Naturally, the important bit to output is the DATA TO SHOW part.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

**UPDATE -----------------------**

```
import re

inputFile = open("small.txt", "r")
output = open("result.txt", "w")


searchStart = "----- ASSERT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
searchEnd = "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"


match = re.findall('^----- ASSERT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n(.*?)---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------', inputFile.read(), re.MULTILINE)
print match,
```

Any ideas how to get it to show all the lines until it hits the searchEnd tag? Example data:

```
----- ASSERT --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MORE
INFO
THAT
I
NEED
TO
GET
FROM
THE
FILE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give sample of what would be between these tags. It can greatly affect the code written for it?

Comment: `-+DATA-+\n.*?\n-+\n`should do it

Comment: The problem is not the language you use but how you process the file. To do what you want without consuming too much memory, you must read your file line by line and when the "opening tag" is reached, start to record the data. Stop the record at the end tag. If you load the whole file in a variable and you process it with a poor pattern, it is normal you encounter memory problems.

Comment: @SidharthShah - The data will be around 15 lines of basic text. I can't really upload one as it includes sensitive data.

Comment: @tutchmedia: only 15 lines and you encounter memory problems! What is the pattern you have tried?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - Sorry, the data between each of the above strings is 15 lines. The full file has thousands of lines.

Comment: @tutchmedia: this is the reason why you must process the file line by line (only the current line use memory).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah that's understandable. Could you point me in the right direction of how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

An example with php (not tested, the idea is here) :

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $record = false;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if ($line == '------DATA--------------------------------------------------') {
            $record = true;
            $temp = '';
        } elseif ($record) {
            if ($line == '------------------------------------------------------------') {
                $record = false;
                $results[] = $temp;
                $temp = '';
            } else $temp .= $line;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Gargoyl, the file can\'t be opened!';
} 
fclose($handle);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks for this :) Is there any way to do it in Python. (Covering my back as all our work machines have python installed.

Comment: Updated my original post with where i've got too on the Python side. I'm stuck now though as i can't get it to pull all the lines until the searchEnd tag.

Any ideas? :)